# v-select2 can not append value after load by $http

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, jquery-select2, vuejs2, vue-component

I using v-select at: https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/

It get data from api:

```
/search/tag?keyword=
```

and I

```
return $tags->toJson(); (laravel)
```

has data return but can not append to options in v-select

View template

```
<template>
   <v-select multiple
    :debounce="250"
    :on-search="getOptions"
    :options="options"
    placeholder="Search Tag...">
      <template slot="option" scope="option" value="option.id">
        {{option.name}}
      </template>
   </v-select>
</template>
```

Vue Script

```
import vSelect from "vue-select"

  export default {
    components: {vSelect},

    data() {
      return {
        options: null
      }
    },
    methods: {
      getOptions(search, loading) {
        loading(true)
        this.$http.post(base_url+'/search/tag', {
          keyword: search
        }).then(resp => {
          // this.options = JSON.stringify(resp.data);
          console.log(resp.data);
          loading(false)
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

Resp in console
[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a slot for options in the documentation.

Comment: yes, i had remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The objects you are returning from your API do not have a `label` property. You can customize the `label` used by `v-select` by adding it as a property.

```
<v-select multiple
  :debounce="250"
  :on-search="getOptions"
  :options="options"
  placeholder="Search Tag..."
  label="name">
</v-select>
```

Here is a working [example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/gRLzNm?editors=1010).

Comment: Thank you, i replace it, and fix any some code. It had working

Answer (score 0):

Since you are returning an object array, define a 'label' designation to your component definition.

From the docs:

```
/**
   * An array of strings or objects to be used as dropdown choices.
   * If you are using an array of objects, vue-select will look for
   * a `label` key (ex. [{label: 'This is Foo', value: 'foo'}]). A
   * custom label key can be set with the `label` prop.
   * @type {Array}
   */
  options: {
    type: Array,
    default() { return [] },
  },
```

Comment: Thank you, i replace it, and fix any some code. It had working